# How to define the prototype of an object in a constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm to creating an object constructor with an object as one of it's properties, and want to add methods to that object's prototype.

Defining it like so doesn't work because the object is instantiated from an object literal and not from a constructor:

```
 function Resource (options) {
    this.self = this;
    this.options = options || {};

    .. other options. ...
    
    // service object that I want to add functions to its prototype
    this.service = {
        request: new XMLHttpRequest(),
        requestMethod: options.requestMethod ||'GET',
    },
    // using prototype actually creates an object called prototype 
    // as a property of the service object.
    this.service.prototype = {
        dataToNode: function(element, parent, data){
            var toAppend = document.createElement(element);
            toAppend.innerHTML = data;
            return parent.appendChild(toAppend);
        },
}
```

Cutting to the chase and using `__proto__` like so works, but `__proto__` is depreciated.

#### How can I add to the objects prototype without using `__proto__`?

```
function Resource (options) {
    this.self = this;
    this.options = options || {};

    .. other options. ...
    
    // service object that I want to add functions to its prototype
    this.service = {
        request: new XMLHttpRequest(),
        requestMethod: options.requestMethod ||'GET',
    },
    // using __proto__ works but its deprciated
    this.service.__proto__ = {
        dataToNode: function(element, parent, data){
            var toAppend = document.createElement(element);
            toAppend.innerHTML = data;
            return parent.appendChild(toAppend);
        },
}
```

Comment: Your use of `__proto__` is entirely replacing the object's prototype. Are you sure that's what you want? Why not just make a separate constructor instead of using Object literal syntax?

Comment: @cookiemonster its not what I want, thanks for clarifying. I just want to add functionality to the prototype.

Comment: Then you could do `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.service).newMethod = ...`, but you'll be adding the method to the prototype of an plain object, which means you'll be adding to `Object.prototype`. A separate constructor will be safer.

Comment: Or do: `this.service = Object.create({dataToNode: function(element, parent, data) {...}});`, which will set the object you pass as the prototype of a new object returned. Then put the `request` and `requestMethod` properties on `this.service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Service(options) {
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.requestMethod = options.requestMethod || 'GET';
}

Service.prototype.dataToNode = function(element, parent, data){
    var toAppend = document.createElement(element);
    toAppend.innerHTML = data;
    return parent.appendChild(toAppend);
};

function Resource (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.service = new Service(this.options);
}
```

Comment: great. I was hoping to define everything in the resource object. Is there away to accomplish that?

Comment: @agconti you can move the code there but that is absurd